# Amazon S3: How to get object size and lastmodified by key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I found only one way to get object size and last modified: it is client.ListObjects() method. But it can returns multiple files by prefix. For example:

```
a.txt
a.txt.bak
```

What is right way to retrieve object size by key?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're correctly inspecting the response? As per the docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property) the size is returned.

UPDATE (since I did't fully understand the question):

I think [headObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property) is what you're looking for: it takes a key and returns metadata of an object. Look at `LastModified` and `ContentLength` in the response.

Comment: I need to get only one size for only one object with specified key. My question is about avoid itterations over ListObjects result.